# vlc command mutes matlab

Tags: matlab, audio, vlc

I am using MATLAB (2018b) and Cogent 2000 toolbox to prepare an experiment which will present a silent video + audio stimuli on the same time. 
So, within the code of the experiment I am using this command:

```
system('start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" --play-and-exit instructionsANDstimuli\Donald.mp4 --no-qt-name-in-title -f -q --width 640 --height 480 --start-time 4 --stop-time 14 --no-osd --no-autoscale --no-keyboard-events --no-mouse-events --intf dummy --dummy-quiet &');
```

Then follows the for loop for the presentation of the audio stimuli.

So, what I am expecting is to watch the silent video while listening to the audio stimuli. Unfortunately, what is happenning is that I am watching only the video with no audio stimuli.

Note that:

1. Donald.mp4 is a silent video
2. When I am running the code without the video I can hear the audio stimuli properly.
3. I have tried the following options with no success: --no-audio, --no-sout-audio, --spdif, --no-audio --no-sout-audio, --no-audio --spdif, --spdif  --no-sout-audio, --no-audio --no-sout-audio --spdif, --spdif, --aout none.

Is there something wrong with the video or audio options in the command system(start ...)? Do you know what may resolve this issue?

Thank you very much for your time!!

Comment: When you run that command on your system console, does it work?

Comment: @AnderBiguri I have to modify it, remove the system part. So, it works like this:    start "" "C:\..etc.... --dummy-quiet

Comment: I understand that. Does it do what you describe? play both things simultaneously?

Comment: @AnderBiguri the command is just for the VLC to start playing the movie not for the sounds. Inside the script after this command there is a for loop to control the presentation of the audio stimuli.

Comment: But I think system locks the MATLAB script until it returns.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Thank you for your time! If you use the '&' at the end of the command it returns and executes the rest of the script.

Comment: I think we need some sort of [mcve] that we can test

Comment: @AnderBiguri Thank you for the suggestion. I think it's mostly a problem caused by Cogent 2000 toolbox, so your suggestion implies that you would have to add also the Cogent 2000 toolbox in the path.